# Format String Value As MM/dd/YYYY

Tags: c#, winforms

I am querying SharePoint and my dates are returned as YYYY-MM-dd 16:27:12 - for display only I tried to modify the syntax to be

```
string dateInfo = xNode.Attributes[“Altered”].Value;
sb.Append(String.Format(“{0:MM/dd/yyyy}”, dateInfo));
```

However that is not formatting the date time. What do i need to change so that the date/time is returned in my required format?

My desired format is mm/dd/yyyy 4:27:12 12 hour format so

Comment: Are you getting the dates as string instead of normal dates?

Comment: You can only do date time formatting on a `DateTime`.  If you have a string that represents a date in one format and you want another you need to first parse it to a `DateTime` then format that to the desired string.

Comment: What is `did`? You mean `dd`?

Comment: Please show what you mean by "my required format". I have never seen a date part specifier "did", what is that? To be clear, that format **will** format a DateTime, it just isn't the format you wanted but since you haven't told us what you wanted, and "did" isn't a commonly used formatting part, it's not entirely clear what the format you're looking for is. And also, just to be clear, you can't **reformat** a string according to a DateTime format, you first have to parse it to a DateTime value before you can format that value.

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to parse it to `DateTime` first:

```
string dateInfo = xNode.Attributes["Altered"].Value;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateInfo);
sb.Append(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt));
```

Comment: This drops the time element

Comment: @HotTomales: sure, because you use `MM/dd/yyyy` as format

Comment: Ah - sorry for my oversight!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try, like:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(dateInfo).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: This drops the time?